# How to use IN operator for joining tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I tried this SQL query but it throws syntax error:

```
select * from table join table1 on (table.int_col in table1.int_array_col)
```

Wrapping `table1.int_array_col` with parenthesises doesn't work. It throws `operator does not exist: integer = integer[]` error for this query:

```
select * from table join table1 on (table.int_col in (table1.int_array_col))
```

The only solution that I found is to replace IN with ANY:

```
select * from table join table1 on (table.int_col = any (table1.int_array_col))
```

However; AFAIK IN operator performs far better than ANY operator. Is there any way to use IN operator in JOIN clause? If it's not possible, what's the reason behind this problem?

Comment: What's the reason for using `IN` for joining?

Comment: @m.edmondson int_array_col is an integer array contains values from int_col column.

Comment: @Mehmet so the question is why are you using arrays of integers and not proper normalization and a junction (association) table...

Comment: @ypercube please do not criticise the table design. this is the schema that I have to work with. If I would be working on a new schema, I would ask that question. It's like always suggesting jquery for javascript related problems.

Comment: No idea what jquery or javascript have to do with the comments or the question. Bad designs should be criticised in my opinion. Please do not request the opposite.

Comment: And please don't name your tables `table`. Do you name your childeren `kid` and `kid1` ?

Comment: Of course you can do whatever you want but this is the schema I HAVE TO WORK WITH. If I would design that schema, yes I would create the proper normalized tables.

Comment: @wildplasser good suggestion. i will pay attention next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual for the `in` operator

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized list of scalar expressions

not an array

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN18448

So yes, for an array you will have to use the `= any` construct

Comment: I think one can also use `ARRAY[int_col] <@ int_array_col` (no idea which is more efficient)